# Realms fails to add object on incoming notification

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, realm

I'm facing currently this issue when using realm in connection with GCM(Google Cloud Messaging). In some cases the app crashes while adding a object to a realm at the point a notification is coming in. The error happens
while the Application state is either active or inactive. However I have no idea if the state has any impact on causing the problem. Probably I'm doing something wrong while adding the incoming object. Does anybody has a hint what could be the reason for this kind of error.

While I was researching on this issue i found out that this kind of errors including "realm::SharedGroup" are strongly connected to situations where a Realm gets written simultaneously.

Stack Trace

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18390953c pthread_mutex_lock + 1294
1  VLC         0x1003d67a8 realm::util::RobustMutex::low_level_lock() + 2292
2  VLC         0x100478ef8 realm::SharedGroup::do_begin_write() + 7996
3  VLC         0x1003a766c realm::_impl::transaction::begin(realm::SharedGroup&, realm::ClientHistory&, realm::BindingContext*, bool) (transact_log_handler.cpp:445)
4  VLC         0x1003a5048 realm::Realm::begin_transaction() (shared_realm.cpp:290)
5  VLC         0x1003946cc -[RLMRealm beginWriteTransaction] (RLMRealm.mm:445)
6  VLC         0x100175c28 -[VLCRealms createOrUpdateObject:] (VLCRealms.m:111)
7  VLC         0x10013857c -[VLCNotificationManager serializeNotification:] (VLCNotificationManager.m:65)
8  VLC         0x100138050 -[VLCNotificationManager recivedNotification:applicationState:] (VLCNotificationManager.m:28)
9  VLC         0x10012a630 -[VLCAppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] (VLCAppDelegate.m:103)
```

Additional Information:

Using Realm (0.98.7)

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using? v0.97.8 doesn't exist, per https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases.

Comment: @bdash Hi sorry my fault v0.98.7 switched the last two digits

Comment: What do you mean by saying this occurs when the app is inactive? Are you periodically trying to perform a write while the app has been backgrounded?

Comment: As written in the description, I'm working with Google Cloud Messaging (Remote notifications) which are also incoming in case a the app is currently in background (inactive)

Comment: Have you seen the hints around [Using Realm with Background App Refresh](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#using-realm-with-background-app-refresh) and made sure that your file is not encrypted by the iOS file system-based encryption?